# Remote Desktop doesn't work over WAN

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop

I've got RDP up and running on Windows 10. I set a custom port, opened it, NAT forwarded
it and created a loopback it in my router. It works when accessing it over LAN when using the local IP and the public IP from inside the same network too.

It doesn't work when I try to access it remotely over the internet.

Just in case I temporarily took the firewall down to test the connection. Still no luck. Online port checkers show the port as open. I'm using the Android RDP app to access the target computer. My router is a MikroTik.

Comment: Are you using the internal IP address or your public IP address?  You shouldn't have to forward your port if you only connect within your internal network.

Comment: What do you mean by "created a loopback" ?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm trying to connect from outside my network. Connecting from within was just to test if RDP itself is working

Comment: @harrymc A hairpin NAT so the router forwards connections to the RDP machine  from within the same network but using the external IP back to its respective local IP. It's not really relevant to my issue (connecting from outside), just extra information about my setup: 
`/ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat action=masquerade protocol=tcp src-address=(Router IP)/24 dst-address=(Local IP) dst-port=(RDP port)`

Comment: If you're trying to access your computer in a loop from your computer and through the internet, your router may possibly not support it.

Comment: @Ramhound  What? The issue is *not* getting it to work from within, and it *is* already working from within.

Comment: @harrymc It supports it. I've done it in the past with this same router. I don't know when exactly it stopped working, I rarely RDP into my desktop over the internet, but a few variables changed since I last successfully did: I changed my ISP, changed the OS version to Windows 10 and updated the router.